# Make background image of td to fit to 100% for non static images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have td tag:

```
<td class="np-logo" style="width: 228px; height: 50px;">
                                            </td>
```

And CSS:

```
.np-logo
{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

And i am changing the image according to company logo.and all images have different-different size and width.

```
.np-logo{background-image:url('" + companylogo + "');
```

The problem is images are not getting fitted to td correctly.i want them to occupy whole td .but for every company the background image position is non uniform.I even tried using java script on image load to fit to container. didn't worked though.

any help guys...?

Comment: Give `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: @Mr_Green:works like charm.....can you post it as answer.ill mark it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

where first value is for width and the second is for height.

You can know more about it by following this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size)

Comment: this was something i was looking for a while

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `cover`?

```
.np-logo {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<td class="np-logo" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%">
```

or this

```
<td class="np-logo" style="max-height: 228px; max-width: 50px">
```